# CCTV cable power rating?

Tags: power, current, resistance, cables, wire

I want to know whether I can use this d-link 3+1 CCTV cable for powering an led strip which runs at 12 volts 1 amp. The led strip is approximately 12 meters away from the smps power adapter. I checked the datasheet of the cable for power ratings on the 3 multi-strand copper wires but they're not given. All that is provided is that there are 14 strands per wire and they're 0.1mm diameter each I think. No cross sectional area or resistance is stated.

[Datasheet for cable](https://cctv.dlink.co.in/product.php?ref=DCC-WHI-90)

Comment: Calculate the area of each strand.  Multiply that by 14 to give you the total current carrying cross section for each wire.  Than look that up in a wire gauge table to see what standard wire size comes close (say #26).  Finally, use the current rating for that size wire and/or the resistance, current, and your voltage drop requirement to see if it meets your need.  You do the work and post it here, and we'll check it for you.

Comment: Telecomms equipment and PoE (power over Ethernet) use 48 V to transfer reasonable amounts of power with small diameter wires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *No cross sectional area or resistance is stated.*

But, you can work that out... a 0.1 mm diameter wire has a CSA (cross sectional area)  of 0.007854 mm² and, given that there are 14 of them, that's a net CSA of 0.11 mm².

Then, google an AWG table and see which wire has the closest net CSA. [Here's one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tnt-audio.com%2Fclinica%2Fawg_e.html&psig=AOvVaw1x3-VMouiXC67k-6975RzG&ust=1644150790230000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCKjAl5HJ6PUCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE): -

[image]

It looks somewhere between AWG 27 and AWG 26. So, google what the current carrying capacity is of [these types of wire](https://meters.co.uk/american-wire-gauge-awg-cable-conductor-sizes/): -

[image]

It looks like 26 AWG is only really recommended for a maximum current of 361 mA so, you might be out of luck.

> *I want to know whether I can use this d-link 3+1 CCTV cable for
> powering an led strip which runs at 12 volts 1 amp.*

I think probably not.

Comment: That was quick. Thank you for helping me out. I guess I'll invest in a new 0.75mm² copper wire. Should have enough current rating and a lower resistance too.